# How to resolve null values correctly during a COALESCE call

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I have a pretty large mysql call which I won't bother showing it all as it's not really important. The part that IS working fine before requiring modification looked like this:

```
COALESCE(d1.apFunReq, d2.apFunReq, d3.apFunReq, d4.apFunReq, d5.apFunReq, d6.apFunReq, d8.apFunReq, d2old.apFunReq, d3old.apFunReq, d5old.apFunReq, '') AS 'Funding Required',
```

This would return all the `apFunReq` values in multiple tables, regardless if null or filled. Worked great, no problems.

Now it's been decided we need another tables data to join the process, however the required data does not sit all in one column on this new table, instead it needs to be added up collectively over 5 columns. So I have implemented this:

```
COALESCE(d1.apFunReq, d2.apFunReq, d3.apFunReq, d4.apFunReq, d5.apFunReq, d6.apFunReq, d8.apFunReq, (IFNULL(d10.reqFunding_01, 0) + IFNULL(d10.reqFunding_02, 0) + IFNULL(d10.reqFunding_03, 0) + IFNULL(d10.reqFunding_04, 0) + IFNULL(d10.reqFunding_05, 0)), d2old.apFunReq, d3old.apFunReq, d5old.apFunReq, '') AS 'Funding Required',
```

Now this does actually work for the new table rows in the result BUT it breaks a significant portion of what was previously returning ok. Now much of the other tables values are just returning as 0.

Clearly I need to return null values to be 0 for data within d10 for the addition to work, but I want null values from the other tables to remain null and I want the data for all tables to obviously work as desired.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong in order to get the desired result. Can someone help me on this please?

C

Comment: well, yeah. coalesce scans the arguments in-order and returns the first non-null one. since your `ifnull()` chain either returns that sum or a zero, it's by definition NEVER null, and the coalesce will always stop there.  move it to the last position in the coalesce call

Comment: Or, if it can't be in the last position because it has precedence over the fields that follow, you may have to wrap that nasty bit of math into a CASE or IF statement to spit out NULL when the return is 0. It won't be very elegant looking and there may be a fancier way of doing it, but ultimately that thing has to return NULL when it's 0.

Comment: I think it is ok to shift to last position, however what will happen if another similar call to another table is then added? Also it seems previously null returns (where they were wanted) are now returning as 0. Can this be easily fixed or would that get more messy and complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to solve this is to use `NULLIF` after you add up all the `IFNULL`ed values like so:

```
 COALESCE(d1.apFunReq, d2.apFunReq, d3.apFunReq, d4.apFunReq, d5.apFunReq, d6.apFunReq, d8.apFunReq, 
   NULLIF(IFNULL(d10.reqFunding_01, 0) + IFNULL(d10.reqFunding_02, 0) + IFNULL(d10.reqFunding_03, 0) + IFNULL(d10.reqFunding_04, 0) + IFNULL(d10.reqFunding_05, 0), 0), 
   d2old.apFunReq, d3old.apFunReq, d5old.apFunReq, '') AS 'Funding Required',
```

Obviously, this doesnt work if 0 is a valid answer though.

Comment: Thank you CSTobey - your solution did work perfectly without the need to even reorder anything. In my situation 0 will never be a valid answer, 0 should always be considered null as a zero amount equals nothing for these terms.